# Virtual Assitant does not pass off to skill on MS teams

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I added a skill to the virtual assistant and uploaded it as an app on MS teams for dev testing. I get the prompt from the VA but it doesn't hand off to the skill. However, when I add the bot to MS teams from the channel section in Web App Bot > MS Teams, it works as intended. The manifest.json file:

```
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/json-schemas/teams/v1.5/MicrosoftTeams.schema.json",
    "manifestVersion": "1.5",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "id": "MICROSOFT APP ID",
    "packageName": "com.xyz.bot",
    "developer": {
        "name": "xyz",
        "websiteUrl": "xyz",
        "privacyUrl": "xyz",
        "termsOfUseUrl": "xyz"
    },
    "icons": {
        "color": "color.png",
        "outline": "outline.png"
    },
    "name": {
        "short": "Test Bot",
        "full": "Test Bot"
    },
    "description": {
        "short": "Test Bot",
        "full": "Test Bot"
    },
    "accentColor": "#F9F9FA",
    "bots": [
        {
            "botId": "MICROSOFT APP ID (same as above)",
            "scopes": [
                "personal",
                "team",
                "groupchat"
            ],
            "supportsFiles": false,
            "isNotificationOnly": false
        }
    ],
    "permissions": [
        "identity",
        "messageTeamMembers"
    ],
    "validDomains": ["token.botframework.com"]
}
```

Would appreciate some help in this matter.. Thanks!

Comment: This is not related to your question, but just fyi, the "MICROSOFT APP ID" is NOT meant to be the same in both places. Your MS Teams APP can contain various things, ONE of which can be a Bot Framework bot, which has a *Microsoft App ID*. The Teams "App ID" is not a "MICROSOFT APP ID", it's just a guid value that needs to be unique in Teams

Comment: Where is you skill hosted?

Comment: Hi Hilton, I kept it the same as it is literally only a bot, thanks for pointing that out! Will ensure to have different IDs in future. 
The skill is hosted on Azure. It works in the emulator and when plugging the bot directly in from the channel. Just not sure why the handover doesn't occur when creating an app....

Comment: When you say it's hosted on azure, do you mean it's running on it's own endpoint to the bot itself? I want to know because I want to understand what's wired up to what in your scenario.

Comment: I followed the deployment guidelines for the VA and skills section. As such, everything is on Azure from using S1 to LUIS. 
[VA deploy](https://microsoft.github.io/botframework-solutions/virtual-assistant/tutorials/deploy-assistant/cli/1-intro/)
[Skills connect to VA deploy](https://microsoft.github.io/botframework-solutions/skills/tutorials/add-prebuilt-skill/3-deploy-skill-project/)

Comment: Have you tried running this locally, and debugging it? Aside from this particular problem, it's useful to do so that you can fix other things that come up. It's a bit of work to get this all working, but it's hugely useful to know what's going on. The setup for this would be the normal process of setting up a local development bot for Teams, so that's well documented.

Comment: Does your VA bot hand off to your skill as expected when you chat with it over webchat?

Comment: See that's the thing, it works fine when I run it locally, web chat as well as when I add the bot to MS teams using the bot ID..